# Number of Columns in another Sheet?

Tags: excel, range

In Excel, what's the function for finding the number of columns between 2 cells in another sheet?

Answer (score 0):

The COLUMNS function.

It is used like this:

```
=COLUMNS(array)
```

Comment: What if I'm trying to calculate data from another sheet, what's the syntax for that?

Comment: =COLUMNS(SheetName!array)

Comment: How about counting the number of none-empty columns from, for example, a given cell to the end of that row

Comment: This will count from the user selected cell (in this case Sheet2,A1) to the final column in the row.  It will only work from Excel 2007 onwards.

    =COUNTA(Sheet2!A1:Sheet2!XFD1)